# WebStorm test shortcut

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, webstorm

Does anyone know why the shortcut to go to the tests for a given class (cmd+shift+t) doesn't work in WebStorm as it does in IntelliJ Idea, or how one can enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cmd+Shift+T` does work in WebStorm; navigation is based on test names (i.e. marking folder as test root won't help here), e.g. performing **Navigate | Test** inside a file named `My.js` will navigate you to `MySpec.js` file.
Patterns are hardcoded to `*Spec.js`, `*_spec.js`, `*-spec.js` (+same patterns with `"test"` instead of `"spec"`). Note that if the file extensions differ (`jsx` > `js`), it won't work..

We have a feature request for making patterns configurable, [WEB-29053](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29053); please feel free to vote for it

Comment: Hows about the creation of a test if one doesn't exist?

Comment: there is no such feature, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25036 for updates

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the root test folder as such, you can do this by marking it by right clicking, "Mark Directory as->Test Sources Root" as below:

[image]

Or alternatively by the project preferences->directories as below:
[image]

After this one should be able to navigate between tests and their source using the cmd+shift+t shortcut.

Comment: If anyone knows how to get it to prompt for the creation of tests if one is not found that would be useful to know...